# How do I copy an array of characters to a member of a struct?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have something like this:

```
struct cd { char name; cd *next;}

// some code...

int main(){
char title[100];

// some code...

cd *p =new cd;
p->name=title;
```

How do I copy the array `title` to `p->name`?

Comment: Just to clarify this... you want to store a string in a linked list of characters?

Comment: Unless you mistyped, `p->name` is a char, `title` a char array, so it's not possible

Comment: actually there s linked list with mush more struct members
 `char act;`
 `char pko;`
 `char name;`
 `cd* next;` and in main() function reads text from file in array and i need to copy in to a struct member. maybe i`m wrong with that `char name;` and should change to `char name[100]` if its possible?

Answer (score 5):

If you use a `std::string`, this gets easy:

```
struct cd { std::string name; cd *next; };

int main() {
    // blah
    p->name = title;
}
```

But you can do better than this. In C++ you can initialize an object with a constructor:

```
struct cd {
    cd(std::string newname) : name(newname), next() {}

    std::string name;
    cd *next;
};

int main() {
    // blah
    cd p(title); // initializes a new cd with title as the name
}
```

If the constructor is undesirable, you can use aggregate initialization:

```
struct cd {
    std::string name;
    cd *next;
};

int main() {
    // blah
    cd p = { title, NULL }; // initializes a new cd with title as the name
                            // and next as a null pointer
}
```

Comment: `+1` from me for answering it as the C++ question it is tagged as. But, actually, this cries for an answer explaining what ctors are for...

Comment: Alternatively, keep the struct a simple aggregate and initialize it in place: `cd p = { "hello", ... };`. Sometimes its nice not to have any custom constructors.

Comment: The constructor should explicitly set `next` to NULL. It should also take a const ref to a std::string as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In your struct you need a char pointer, not a single char:

```
struct cd {
    char * name;
    cd *next;
}
```

so, your final code would become:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char title[256];

    // code

    struct cd * p = new cd;
    p->name = new char[256];
    strcpy(p->name, title);
}
```

note that this is pure **C** (apart from the new, that could be replaced by a malloc()) and not C++.

Comment: This is also broken in that `strcpy` will attempt to write to unallocated memory; `p->name` is uninitialized. You could fix (and simplify) this by just using `strdup`.

Comment: Are you sure about this? "new" in pure "C"? strcpy to unallocated memory?

Comment: oops, indeed. Also, a struct like that is so prone to memory leaks.